# Destruction of class object upon interrupt signal

Tags: c++, c++11

I am developing c++ application and I am stucked on the signal handling problem with c++11.
I want to call destructor's for all objects(created on stack as well as on heap) created under my main application on arrival of SIGINT signal.

Please suggest sophisticated solution here.
Appriciate for you time.

Thanks and Regards,
Ojas

Comment: Why don't you just create a signal handler, and destroy your objects there?

Comment: Singnal hanlder can not be a class member.

Comment: And what if I have created heiracy of objects.

Comment: See working example below!

Comment: If you have a hierarchy of objects, just call delete on the most top level objects inside the handler, and make sure that each object deletes all its children in its destructor!

Comment: Very few things in C++ are signal-safe. Pretty much nothing, actually.

Comment: @Sam: Updated my example below to avoid the issue with functions being called from the async signal handler!

Comment: @skriptkiddie I know all that you posted but what if I don't want to use global pointers?

Comment: Works with a local pointer just as fine! Just move it into main() and you can see it works!

Comment: Scope absolutely everything in a loop. On detection of the signal, put on your cape and cowl... No. Wait. That's Batman. On detection of the signal, set a flag. Everybody checks the flag and bails out. control returns to the loop and it loops, destroying everything and recreating it on the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ojas, I posted a second answer how you can make objects destroy themselves when not needed anymore without out having to destroy them explicitly. (using shared_ptr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different solution is to use shared_ptr. "Shared objects" will destroy themselves at the end of your program! Just make sure to catch the SIGINT properly and exit() gracefully.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class Crap {
    public:
    Crap() {};
    ~Crap() {printf("destructor called\n");} 
};
int main(void)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Crap> cc = std::make_shared<Crap>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ass@xxx:/tmp$ ./a.out 
destructor called
```

## FULL EXAMPLE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <csignal>

using namespace std;

class Crap {
    public:
    Crap() {};
    ~Crap() {printf("destructor called\n");} 
};

static volatile sig_atomic_t got_signal = 0;
void signalHandler( int signum ) {
     // AVOID REENTRANCY !!!!
     got_signal = 1;
}
int main(void)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Crap> cc = std::make_shared<Crap>();
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);  

    while(1) {
        cout << "PLEASE GIVE ME A SIGINT SIGNAL" << endl;
        if(got_signal == 1){
            break;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your program is written well, there is very little that needs to be done to make sure all destructors are called. Here is one method.

1. When you want all destructors to be called, throw an exception. This starts [stack unwinding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw#Stack_unwinding).
2. Catch the exception in your `main` function. At this point, the stack unwinding has called the destructor for each variable with automatic [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration), aside from (possibly some of) the variables declared in the `main` function itself.
3. Do a `return` from the `main` function. This will call the destructor for the remaining variables with automatic storage duration. Then [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) will be invoked, which calls the destructors of all objects with thread local or static storage duration.

This explicitly covers all objects except those with dynamic storage duration. It implicitly covers those dynamic objects, though, since I qualified this with the condition that your program is written well. To me, a well-written program should use [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) to clean up dynamic memory as a consequence of the non-dynamic variables being cleaned up.

If you don't use RAII, you most likely have a headache on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Example for the heap objects - complete it to your needs! Run it and give it a SIGINT signal by pressing CTRL+C:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <csignal>
  #include <unistd.h>
  using namespace std;

  class Crap {
    public:
    Crap() {};
    ~Crap() {printf("destructor called\n");} 
  };

  Crap* p;
  static volatile sig_atomic_t got_signal = 0;

  void signalHandler( int signum ) {
     // AVOID REENTRANCY !!!!
     got_signal = 1;
  }

  int main () {
     signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);  

     // ON HEAP
     p = new Crap;


     while(1) {
        cout << "PLEASE GIVE ME A SIGINT SIGNAL" << endl;
        if(got_signal == 1){
            delete p; // DELETE OBJECT ON HEAP AND CALL DESTRUCTOR 
            exit(0);
        }
        sleep(1);
     }

     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Revised, to avoid reentrancy issues!